# Rename file before copy to certain folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, rename-item-cmdlet

I´m a newbie still and learning to create PowerShell scripts to make Life in IT easier.

At present I´m trying to build a script, which runs a certain Microsoft tool, scanning defined network shares in a csv file and creating an JSON output file.
Now as the pattern of this file is always the same like "Report_Username_Hostname.vba.JSON", I would like to append either the scanned directory name or even a range of numbers, fe. "Report_Username_Hostname(100).vba.JSON" or "Report_Username_Hostname(sharename).vba.JSON"

This is neccessaray as after this renaming step, I upload this and other files within this folder to another folder on different server to upload them into a Database.
I planned to run this script in in many different locations on most automatic level and they all copy the their collected files to just one upload folder.

I already tried several options I found somewhere in the deep of the Internet, but I only came to the point where the file was renamed to 0 or similar, but not to expected result.

The Powershell script doing the work is this:

```
 $PSpath = 'C:\temp\FileRemediation\Scripts\'
 $Rpath = $PSpath +'..\Reports\1st'
 $localshare = $PSpath +'..\temp\1st'
 $csvinputs = Import-Csv $PSpath\fileremediation_1st.csv
 $uploadshare = '\\PGC2EU-WFSFR01.eu1.1corp.org\upload\'

# This section checks if the folder for scan reports is availabe and if not will create necessary folder.
If(!(test-path $Rpath))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Rpath
} 
If(!(test-path $localshare))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $localshare
}
Set-Location $Rpath

# This section reads input from configuration file and starts Ms ReadinessReportCreator to scan shares in configuration file. 
ForEach($csvinput in $csvinputs)
{
    $uncshare = $csvinput.sharefolder

    $Executeable = Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft xxx\xxx.exe" `
    -Argumentlist "-p ""$uncshare""", "-r", "-t 10000", "-output ""$localshare"""`
    -Wait
   Get-ChildItem -Path $localshare -Filter '*.JSON' | Rename-Item     -NewName {$_.FullName+$uncshare}
}
# This section copies the output *.JSON file of the xxx to the share, where I they will be uploaded to DB.        
Get-ChildItem -Path $localshare -Filter '*.JSON' | Where {$_.Length -ge 3} | move-item -Destination '$uploadshare'
```

the fileremediation_1st.csv looks like

```
sharefolder
\\server\sharename
```

Can someone please help me on this, I don´t have a clue what I´m doing wrong.
Thank you!

Current error I get is

> Rename-Item : Cannot rename the specified target, because it
>   represents a   path or device name. At
>   C:\temp\FileRemediation\scripts\fileremediation_V2_1st.ps1:28 char:55
>   + ... share -Filter '*.JSON' | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.FullName+$uncshare}
>   +                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item],     PSArgumentException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

As said before, I would also be fine with a dedicated range of numbers, which is append to the file name "Report_Username_Hostname(100).vba.JSON"
The perfect world would  be if I could split the \server\sharename from csv file and append the sharename to my filename.

Comment: Best solution I found so far is      Get-ChildItem -Path $localshare -Filter '*.JSON' | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace(".vba","_EU.vba")}  but it keeps renaming to endless _EU_EU_EU_EU if I have many files in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with:

```
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.FullName+$uncshare}
```

Your input file (`Get-ChildItem`) path is:

```
$PSpath = 'C:\temp\FileRemediation\Scripts\'
$localshare = $PSpath +'..\temp\1st'
```

The `Rename-Item` uses `$_.FullName` which resolves to something like this:

```
C:\temp\FileRemediation\Scripts\..\temp\1st\MyFile.JSON
```

The variables then contain:

```
$_.FullName = C:\temp\FileRemediation\Scripts\..\temp\1st\MyFile.JSON
$uncshare = "\\server\sharename"
```

So Your `Rename-Item ... $_.FullName+$uncshare` will try to rename it to:

```
C:\temp\FileRemediation\Scripts\..\temp\1st\MyFile.JSON\\server\sharename
```

Which is not a valid path.

Comment: OK, but what would you suggest to change?

Comment: The problem in the error message is that you can't have slashes (e.g. the UNC path) in the filename which is why the rename is failing. So replace `$uncshare` with something else like `"server_sharename_JSON"`